# Odd name of Grid in WPF project

Tags: wpf, grid, naming-conventions

I am currently working on a large WPF application.  Yet the previous developers seemed to name numerous grids with the word 'Top'.  'Top' is a reserved word in System, so I have to go in and change numerous instances of this.  But I don't understand why they would do such a thing in the first place.  Any ideas people?

thanks in advance...

Comment: AFAIK `Top` is not a reserved word. Could you please explain your problem in detail?

Comment: I changed all the instances of where Grids were named "Top", yet before I did, I was getting a warning along the lines of the name Top in *.xaml hides the system keyword Top.  Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.  More importantly, I just can't figure out why the previous developers would name so many grids with x:Top

Comment: Specific warning: *Shell.Top' hides inherited member 'System.Windows.Window.Top'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: do you have a class `Shell` that inherits from `Window`?

Comment: No Shell is part of my project namespace, it is simply a xaml file

Answer (score 1):

From the error message it can be deduced that:

- your `Shell` classes is derived from `System.Windows.Window` (either directly or indirectly)
- `Top` is not a keyword, but an inherited property of the parent class `Window`
- naming a panel `Top` conflicts with the parent class, because adding the name implicitly creates a property in the derived class

I guess that the code is just copy-and-pasted from another location, where it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the name "Top" was relevant precisely once (perhaps where the `Grid` was docked to the top of its container), and the rest came about due to copy+paste coding.